# Auto punctuation with csquotes and babel

Tags: babel, csquotes

I am using `csquotes` to manage my quotes in a document using American English. My code is basically as follows.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

This is \enquote{my splendid quote}.

\end{document}
```

**This is rendered as:** This is "my splendid quote".

**What I want:** This is "my splendid quote."

Is there any way to automate it while still using `\enquote`? I thought the `autopunct` option would do the trick but apparently not.

Comment: Did you see the posting [No support for American-style punctuation in csquotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211961/5001)? (Try running `\renewcommand{\mktextquote}[6]{#1#2\ifblank{#4}{#5}{#4}#3#6}` followed by 
`\let\enquote\textquote`.)

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much! I saw other posts, but not this one. I ended up doing
`\renewcommand{\mktextquote}[6]{#1#2\ifblank{#4}{#5}{#4}#3#6}` and `\renewcommand{\enquote}[1]{\textquote{#1}}`, which worked beautifully